# Hiphop custom extension

Tags: c++, hiphop

I am trying to create a simple hello world extension using HipHop version 2.1.0. I read the docs in doc/extension.development. However, I believe these are now outdated. I followed the instructions anyways

1. EXT= make -C idl install
2. cmake .
3. make

   error: ‘q_UConverter$$EBCDIC_STATEFUL’ was not declared in this scope

Except there are a lot of these. The file that generates these errors seem to be the `class_map.cpp` file. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So, from what it looks like it seems that the make files are outdated.